# UITableView: Rename Edit Button (UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I am using an `Edit` button in my navigation toolbar to set the table view to the editing mode. The bar button's label defaults to `Edit`.

How can I change its label to something else?

I can't use any other BarButton type, because I need to set the table in its editing mode and I want to get the `setEditing:animated:` behaviour which is triggered by the built-in `Edit` button.

```
self.editToolbarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
   initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit 
   target:self action:@selector(setSearchEditMode:)];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create your own button with two labels.

```
UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title1" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(setSearchEditMode:)];
btn.possibleTitles = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"Title1", @"Title2", nil];
self.editToolbarButton = btn;

- (void)setSearchEditMode:(UIBarButtonItem *)button {
    // Toggle the view controller's editing state
    [self setEditing:!self.editing animated:YES];

    // Update the button's title
    button.title = self.editing ? @"Title2" : @"Title1";

    // other processing
}
```